# I really got stuck about context managers (__enter__ & __exit__) and mysql.connector with an error

Tags: python, mysql-python, with-statement, python-class

I wrote a class to collect data from MySQL db.
I didn't understand how to use the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods when I use the `with`.

More specifically, I don't understand:

1. Where should I return the `self.raws = self.crouser.execute(self.que)` is actually the data from the db.
2. Until when the connection is going to be open?
3. How to use the `with` method in this specific problem?

My code :

```
import mysql.connector

class tak:
     def __init__(self,host1, user1, password1, db1,aat, que1):
          self.host = host1
          self.user = user1
          self.password = password1
          self.database = db1
          self.auth_plugin = aat
          self.que = que1

     def co(self):
          try:
               self.my = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host = self.host,
                    user = self.user,
                    password = self.password,
                    database = self.database,
                    auth_plugin = self.auth_plugin,
                    charset = 'utf8'
               )
          except mysql.connector.errors as err :
               print(f'{err}')
          self.crouser = self.my.cursor()
          self.raws = self.crouser.execute(self.que)
          self.crouser.fetchall()

     def __enter__(self):
          return

     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
          self


with tak(host1="localhost",
         user1="root",
         password1="1234",
         db1="local_db",
         aat='mysql_native_password',
         que1='select * from nand').co() as log:
     print(log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of explanation below:

`__enter__` prepares stuff (opens stuff that should be later closed and such). If you want to do `with ... as ...`, then returned object should be the one that you want to get in `as ...` (very often it's `self` but it doesn't have to be).

`__exit__` should clean up stuff - close stuff that should be closed, reassign stuff their original values...

I have no idea why you're doing the query in the constructor already. **The classic way would be: `__enter__` opens connection, `__exit__` closes. Then any query is in the block.**

Compare to file operations:

```py
f = open(filename)
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Becomes:

```py
with open(filename) as f: # __enter__ returns self
    data = f.readlines()
# we exit the block, so __exit__ is performed - it does f.close() for us
```

While your code is more like...

```py
with open_and_read(filename) as data:
    # ????? do something with data I guess?
```

You do exactly that: open stuff and do one predefined thing... and get stuff that is not closeable, so it could live for longer (right now it lives only inside the `with` block).

**If that's really what you wanted, then ditch context managers altogether: just do a function that opens connection, gets the query, closes connection, returns `log`.**

But if you want a correct context manager, it would probably look like this:

```py
import mysql.connector
class tak :
     def __init__(self,host1, user1, password1, db1,aat): #removed query
          self.host = host1
          self.user = user1
          self.password = password1
          self.database = db1
          self.auth_plugin = aat
          # self.que = que1 nope, we don't want it here

     def __enter__(self):
          self.my = mysql.connector.connect(
              host = self.host,
              user = self.user,
              password = self.password,
              database = self.database,
              auth_plugin = self.auth_plugin,
              charset = 'utf8'
          )
          return self.my.cursor()
     
     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
          self.my.close()
     

# now we can get database info once but open the connection multiple times
db = tak(...)
with db as cur: # our __enter__ returns the cursor
    cur.execute(...)
    data1 = cur.fetchall()
# as we exit the block, __exit__ is called

# do something with data1

with db as cur: # open new connection, return new cursor
    cur.execute(...)
    ...
...
```

[I haven't tested this code, it might need some adjustments. The point of my answer was to explain proper usage of context managers rather than to give perfect code.]

Answer (score 0):

You should perform all the initialization in the `__enter__` method and make it return the context manager instance, and you should perform cleanups in the `__exit__` method:

```
class tak:
     def __init__(self,host1, user1, password1, db1,aat, que1):
          self.host = host1
          self.user = user1
          self.password = password1
          self.database = db1
          self.auth_plugin = aat
          self.que = que1

     def __enter__(self):
          try:
               self.my = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host = self.host,
                    user = self.user,
                    password = self.password,
                    database = self.database,
                    auth_plugin = self.auth_plugin,
                    charset = 'utf8'
               )
          except mysql.connector.errors as err :
               print(f'{err}')
          self.crouser = self.my.cursor()
          self.raws = self.crouser.execute(self.que)
          self.crouser.fetchall()              
          return self
     
     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
          self.my.close()
```

so that you can instantiate it as a context manager directly:

```
with tak(host1="localhost",
          user1="root",
          password1="1234",
          db1="local_db",
          aat='mysql_native_password',
          que1='select * from nand') as log:
     # do something with log here
```

Comment: Hey Thanks  , but when i run it and print the outcome : 

with tak(host1="localhost",
          user1="root",
          password1="1234",
          db1="local_db",
          aat='mysql_native_password',
          que1='select * from nand') as log:
                    print(log) 


I get the Output : None

Comment: Are you sure you have `return self` in the `__enter__` method? It sounds as if you don't have a `return` statement, like you don't in the question.